# laravel - 404 page not found custom domain

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I just did new config to access my page via `domain` : `app.dev` not `localhost:8000` like it was earlier.

I changed `env` file, config file, changed apache2 conf but it's still not working on custom domain (on localhost its working ok)

Comment: its still on localhost ( linux  - Ubuntu 16.04 lts)

Comment: Are you gonna react on something? You still didn't accept an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to edit your hostfile. Please check the following pages for more info:

**Ubuntu**
https://docs.acquia.com/article/using-etchosts-file-custom-domains-during-development

**Windows**
https://bowerwebsolutions.com/how-to-edit-your-local-host-file-for-testing-web-sites/

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your apache2 server is aware of the new url.

Add the following line to the `/etc/hosts` file:

`127.0.0.1    app.dev`

Important: Don't forget to reload your local webserver!

Comment: but i have it ! only thing which is not working are urls after slash for example app.dev/login, app.dev is working but app.dev/another link is not working

Comment: Do you have 127.0.0.1:8000 in your hosts file?

Comment: Edit `etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`and set `AllowOverride All`

Answer (score 0):

Ok now it's working but on domain: app.dev:8000. How can i remove this port from address?